# Sending float from JNI to Java code adds 2 numbers

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

In my JNI I call a function from the OpenCL Class (java). I pass a float as argument but when I print it, it adds 2 diggits.

JNI sending code:

```
float ndrangeDuration =
    (end.tv_sec + end.tv_usec * 1e-6) - (start.tv_sec + start.tv_usec * 1e-6);

LOGD("NDRangeKernel time: %f", ndrangeDuration);

jclass MyJavaClass = (*env).FindClass("com/denayer/ovsr/OpenCL");
if (!MyJavaClass){
    LOGD("Aj :(");
    return;} /* method not found */
jmethodID setTimeFromJNI = (*env).GetMethodID(MyJavaClass, "setTimeFromJNI", "(F)V");
(*env).CallVoidMethod(thisObject, setTimeFromJNI, ndrangeDuration);
```

The LOGD is:

```
#define  LOGD(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__)
```

The java code:

```
public void setTimeFromJNI(float time)
{
    Log.i("setTimeFromJNI","Time set on " + String.valueOf(time));

}
```

Output:

NDRangeKernel time: 0.104581 This is from the JNI

Time set on 0.10458103 This is from the Java

Can someone tell me what I do wrong or don't see?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value is the same, it's just printed differently.

From the `printf(3)` man page:

```
   f, F   The double argument is rounded and converted to decimal notation
          in the style [-]ddd.ddd, where the number of  digits  after  the
          decimal-point character is equal to the precision specification.
          If the precision is missing, it is taken as 6; if the  precision
          is  explicitly  zero,  no decimal-point character appears.  If a
          decimal point appears, at least one digit appears before it.
```

You'll note that, when printed from JNI, the value has 6 digits after the decimal point.  If you used "%.8f" instead of "%f", you'd see the same string of digits on both sides.

You can see the Java-language floating-point format code in Android [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/kitkat-release/luni/src/main/java/java/lang/RealToString.java).  Note the output length does not have a fixed cap.

If your goal is to have matching output, you can use [String.format()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) to print the values from code written in the Java programming language.  The full description of what it accepts is in [Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html); if you dig through it far enough you will find:

> The number of digits in the result for the fractional part of m or a is equal to the precision. If the precision is not specified then the default value is 6.

which matches the native `printf()` behavior.